# What is the geometric interpretation of a complex matrix times a real vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If a real vector is left-multiplied by a real matrix, the geometric interpretation is that this vector is rotated and scaled by the matrix. (Or so I understand).

If on the other hand we left-multiply by a complex matrix, what is the geometric interpretation of the result of this transformation?

Thank you.

Comment: Here you probably want to consider complex numbers in polar form. In that case, a complex-valued matrix would be a linear operator which changes the phase and/or magnitude of a vector.

Comment: @Math1000 Very interesting... would you mind expanding this into an answer? It seems quite insightful! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$"Rotated and scaled by the matrix" is too qualitative to be correct or incorrect. (Note, however, that not every matrix is a product of a rotation matrix and a scalar matrix.)

It would be more accurate (though less descriptive) to say that multiplication on the left by an $m \times n$ complex matrix $A$ defines a linear transformation $T_{A}:\Cpx^{n} \to \Cpx^{m}$. If $A$ happens to be real, this transformation *preserves the real subspaces*, i.e., maps $\Reals^{n} \subset \Cpx^{n}$ to $\Reals^{m} \subset \Cpx^{m}$. Conversely, a linear transformation $T:\Cpx^{n} \to \Cpx^{m}$ that maps $\Reals^{n}$ to $\Reals^{m}$ has only real entries in its standard matrix (because the columns of the standard matrix are the images of the standard basis vectors).

Comment: Thank you: While I realize that such a transformation is linear, what I am trying to understand, is what this might geometrically signify. Perhaps we should start with something simpler: Let us say that $A$ is a real matrix, of size $N$x$N$. If this matrix left multiplies an input $x$, then we can we safely say that the result is another vector that has been rotated and scaled? Now, repeat this experiment for a case where $A$ is a complex matrix, but also of size $N$ x $N$. What is the geometric interpretation of the resultant complex vector after the multiplication? Thank you!

Comment: The point is, a complex vector space may be identified with a real vector space of twice the dimension, so (up to this identification) there's nothing more mysterious about multiplying by a complex matrix than multiplying by a real matrix.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I have other questions on the linear mappings/embedding, but I will put that into another question. Thanks!